# Why is pandahause not work in CI/CD gitlab?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I try set CI/CD in gitlab: i have simple query in python file. There are i use several libs for example seaborn, pandas, pandahouse in this file. All ibs work, but lib 'pandahouse' don't want to work - returns error: 'Encountered error while generating package metadata.╰─> pandahouse'. If i change code (without 'import pandahouse') and delete rows in yml file in script 'pip install pandahouse' then algorithm performs without errors.

Please help me to solve this problem.

My yml file with scripts:

```
image: python:3-alpine

stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy

send_info:

    stage: test
    before_script:
    - pip3 install sphinx  
    
    script:
        - pip install --upgrade pip --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - pip install auxlib --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - pip install seaborn --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - pip install openpyxl --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - pip install pandas --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - pip install pyTelegramBotAPI --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - pip install Python-IO --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - python -m pip install -U matplotlib --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
        - pip install pandahouse --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver

        - echo 'Hello'
        - python bot_test2.py
```

I tried differens libs

Comment: check if pandahouse has any external dependencies that are not installed in your environment or if it is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem: need to write version pandahouse:
'pip install pandahouse==0.2'